# Identify missing values from array

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, excel

I am striving to create a function in VBA that calculates the number of missing values in each column of a matrix of nxn dimensions.

Each column should contain the numbers 1 to n only once. 
However if this is not the case I want to the function to state how many values are missing. For example in a column of  4x4 matrix (1,2,1,3) there is one missing value which is 4, and the function should return the value 1, for the 1 missing value.

I am very new to VBA and by no means a master, but this is what I have done so far...

```
Function calcCost(sol() As Integer, n As Integer) As Integer

Dim ArrayOfTruth(1 To n) As Boolean 


    For Row = 1 To n
        For i = 1 To n
            If ProbMatrix(Column, Row) = i Then
                ArrayOfTruth(i) = True

    cost = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        If ArrayOfTruth(i) = True Then
            cost = cost + 1
```

Comment: What value should be returned for a non-square range?
What value should be returned for the matrix {(1,2), (5,6)} ?

Comment: I'm unclear on how **(1,2,1,3)** is a 4×4 matrix; seems to be either a 1×4 or 4×1 matrix; probably the former. A 4×4 matrix would be something like **((1,2,1,3),(1,1,1,3),(3,2,3,3),(2,2,1,1))**.

Comment: @pnuts - VBA arrays drive me nuts (no pun intended). Transpose or not transpose, single column or row always becomes two dimensional array, etc, etc.

Comment: @pnuts Is there a way to constrain a function's range parameter such that it need be square? I think a non-square range would need to be tested for within the function.

Comment: @pnuts Ah thank you. I'd interpreted this completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the requirement of a square range of cells supersedes the description of the 'matrix's' values, I'm not sure why an array is needed at all.

```
Function calcCost(rTopLeft As Range, n As Long)
    Dim c As Long, r As Long

    For c = 1 To n
        If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(rTopLeft.Resize(n, n), c)) Then _
            r = r + 1
    Next c
    calcCost = r

End Function
```

Syntax:

=calcCost(*<top left corner of desired range>, <number of cells both right and down>*)

Example:

```
=calcCost(E9, 18)
```

The above implementation could also be written as,

```
=18-SUMPRODUCT(--SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(E9,0,0,18,18), ROW(1:18))))
```